# Recursive CoreData Relationships

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, datamodel

I'm modelling the data model for an app and have a case where I want an entity to be able to contain entities of the same entity. This screenshot should clarify the case:

[image]

**Item** is an entity that can either be a stack or a card (determined by the '**type**' attribute in it. If it's a stack it will have a relation to a **StackProperties** entity. However, Stacks can contain both cards and stacks (so stacks can be wrapped into stacks).

The '**items**' relation in the **StackProperties** entity refers to any **Items** that could be in the stack, and these items could be either cards or stacks.

Question: Is this a proper way of modelling this scenario or is there a better way to achieve this structure? I'm asking because Xcode warns me that **StackProperties.items** has no inverse relationship, which isn't a good practice. How would this issue best be solved? Since **Item** already has a (two-way) relation to **StackProperties** (stackProperties <-> owner) I doubt it's a good solution to add another one for the 'items' relation, to make it inverse.

Comment: holding references to each other in different entities is regular practice if the actual _queries_ (i.e. predicates) cannot extract the necessary information in more efficient way. the database's structure usually should be built up for serving _all_ mandatory queries on the most efficient way – therefore if you know what type of information you want to extract in runtime, you should built the hierarchy for those.

Comment: Ok thanks, I will try changing the model structure. Is is probably better to make StackProperties and CardProperties to be actual sub-entities of Item anyway.